# Ruby on Rails ActiveSupport or plain Ruby way of merging arrays into a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's a smart way of using ActiveSupport or perhaps regular built in Ruby functionality to take two arrays and merge them into a hash where each element in an array matches the element in a parallel array? imagine two arrays:

```
names = ["Danny", "Johnny"]
ages = ["25", "32"]
```

The end result should be a hash that looks like:

```
{"Danny" => "25", "Johnny" => "32"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ruby 1.8.7 or above:

```
Hash[names.zip ages]
```

or for 1.8.6:

```
Hash[*names.zip(ages).flatten]
```

Comment: using .flatten will cause problems in the case where either array also contains other arrays. In this specific situation it'll be fine, but important to keep in mind

Comment: Good point, replace `.flatten` with `.sum` if there is any chance of the arrays having other arrays in them.